# $f$ may be continuous at $a$ despite the fact that the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $a$ is undefined

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, continuity

[image]

This is a question from the inquiry-based note [limit](http://danaernst.com/teaching/mat431f21/Limits.pdf)

I am sort of surprised that continuity exists but the limit is undefined. I come up with this example not sure if this is what the highlighted takes about.

$$f:[3,7]\cup\{10\}\to\ \mathbb{R}\\x\mapsto x$$

Does this example satisfies the limit at $10$ do not exist but the function is continuous at $10$?

Comment: why just down-voted? Being nice could just leave an answer YES or NO

Comment: The text is talking of continuity at isolated points. This is just for sake of completeness and by definition every function is continuous at isolated points. The analytical concept of continuity is more about continuity at an accumulation point.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. A perhaps less artificial example is the continuous function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^4-x^2}$, for which $x=0$ is an isolated point of the domain.